# PostgreSQL : FATAL: could not open log file "/path/to/log/filesystem/postgresql-Sun.log": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am new to PostgreSQL and stuck on an issue that PostgreSQL isn't starting up. It reported:

> FATAL:  could not open log file "/path/to/log/filesystem/postgresql-Sun.log": No such file or directory
> 06:52:32.530 UTC [7440] LOG:  database system is shut down

I tried to find the solution online and changed the permission of the `postgres` user using `chown`, but that also didn't help or maybe I missed something.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that user `postgres` has "read" (`r`) and "execute" (`x`) permissions on all directories on the path, and (additionally) "write" (`w`) permissions on the last directory.

Answer (score 0):

User, which runs postgresql, often `postgres`, must be able to traverse to this `/path/to/log/filesystem/` (often `/var/log/postgresql`), specified by `log_directory` config option and be able to write files there. If this path does not exist, you will get `No such file or directory` error.

You can try switching to this user (e.g. `su postgres`) and check `cd /path/to/log/filesystem` (whatever this path really is) and if that throws error, then create the directories (e.g. `mkdir -p /path/to/your/log_directory`).

There's also a possibility that service manager changes mount points for the service, like `systemd` is capable of.